# Error 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal' in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

Writing in a table while including the schema is failing on PySpark with Python 3.

Here are the steps that are working.

```
a = sc.textFile("ad_actions.csv")
b = a.map(lambda x:  x.split('||')).toDF()
b.write.saveAsTable('AD_ACTIONS', mode='append')
```

But if I try to add the schema, it is failing:

```
a = sc.textFile("ad_actions.csv")
b = a.map(lambda x:  x.split('||')).toDF(schema=sqlContext.table("AD_ACTIONS").schema)
b.write.saveAsTable('AD_ACTIONS', mode='append')
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Does any of you know how I can fix this?
Do you need to see anything?

Comment: Logic doesnt seems to have any issue. What is your data look like , post sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue means that you are adding a Schema that don't belongs to the data.

The issue:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Means that you want to cast your string to ordinal. This a function for [date](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.toordinal).

So, the problem is that you are not able to convert the data to the schema that you want.

What I suggest you, take only the name of the columns. Like this:

```
a = sc.textFile("ad_actions.csv")
b = a.map(lambda x:  x.split('||')).toDF(sqlContext.table("AD_ACTIONS").schema.names)
b.write.saveAsTable('AD_ACTIONS', mode='append')
```

This will work fine, due to the schema convertion will be handle by your Metadata Store.